# Add second custom cell in CollectionView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm facing out a problem... I'm trying to add a new custom cell for show native ads in my CollectionView and basically I'm saying that every

```
indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 5
```

there should appear the cell related to the ads. The problem now is, the adsCell is correctly appearing but it took place of the other content.

So if before I was having a collectionView with all the cell with a label with written from 1 to 10, now I have something like: 1, ADSCell, 3,4, ADSCell, and so on.

So basically it's skipping the number 2 that now is replaced by the adsCell and also the number 5.

How can I keep the content but place between them the adsCell?

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return itemsViewModel.itemsModel.featuredItems.value.count
        }else {
            return itemsViewModel.itemsModel.dailyItems.value.count
        }

    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "itemCell", for: indexPath) as! DailyItemCollectionViewCell

        let cellAds = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "adsCell", for: indexPath)

        if indexPath.section == 0{

            if indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 5 {
                return cellAds
            }else {
                print("INDEX", indexPath)
                let featuredItems = itemsViewModel.itemsModel.featuredItems.value[indexPath.row]
                cell.configure(with: featuredItems)
            }
        }else {
            let dailyItems = itemsViewModel.itemsModel.dailyItems.value[indexPath.row]
            cell.configure(with: dailyItems)
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not good practice to have index dependent `if-statement` in `cellForItemAt` function, it's better for you to make `dataSource` more generalize so it can contain ad items, for example, you can set `type` for each `dataSource` items to indicate that its ad or not, then you should put ad item to index 2 and 5 of `dataSource`, then in `cellForItemAt` for each item, you check that type, if its ad return ADSCell if its not return the cell you want.

Answer (score 0):

When indexPath.row equals 2 or 5 you are using the ADSCell, but you then don't account for this when getting the next item from the array.

Try adding an offset counter for every time ADSCell is used then adjust the regular cell assignments by the offset.

```
let featuredItems = itemsViewModel.itemsModel.featuredItems.value[indexPath.row-offset]
```

You'll also need to account for your collection view having more items than the data source array.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? How and where should I take care of "offset"

Comment: Before you return an adsCell you can increment an offset variable by 1. As stated above by @farhad this isn't the ideal solution though. Consider changing your datasource to accommodate different cell types.